# Windows Server Does Not Send IP Packet If Source IP Not Bound To The Sending NIC

Tags: windows, server, tcp, wintun

I am constructing an ip-ip tunnel between remote linux server and the local windows server.

The windows server does not support raw ip-ip tunnel so I develop a simple app which makes usage of wintun.

Said the local windows server is bound to ip_local, the remote linux server is bound to ip_remote, and the tunnel ip is ip_tun.

Currently, the windows server can receive the incoming packet (outer ip_remote->ip_local, inner ip_client->ip_tun) from the remote linux server in the tunnel.

For the outgoing packet (ip_tun->ip_client), if I route the packet to the tun NIC, the packet can be sent out.

However, if I route the packet to the real NIC, the packet is ignored.

Thus there seems a mechanism that blocks the sending of packets when the source ip is not bound to the corresponding NIC.
(In the above case, because ip_tun is not bound to the real NIC, the outgoing packet is ignore.)

Is there any configuration that can disable such mechanism?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bind the server to 0,0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Enable ip routing in registry then everything ok.